# How do I rename the default postgres superuser to "root"?

Tags: postgresql, gentoo

I currently log in to PostgreSQL using `psql -U postgres`. How do I rename `postgres` user to `root`?

If I am already logged in as `postgres` then trying `ALTER USER postgres RENAME TO root` will say `ERROR:  session user cannot be renamed`.

Is it possible to rename the user without logging as `postgres` user? I don't think I have any other superuser since this is a fresh install of PostgreSQL.

By the way, I am running Gentoo on Amazon EC2.

Comment: I'd imagine: log in as postgres, create a second super user, log in as new superuser, and run your ALTER

Comment: Why would you do this?  You can't run the postmaster as "root" as it will only start when run as an unprivileged user.

Comment: Does the `postgres` user in Linux have to match with the `postgres` role in the database? I log in as `root` so I just want to type `psql -d something` to log in as oppose to `psl -U postgres -d something`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to just create a new postgres superuser called root by logging in as the postgres user and (at the shell) typing;

```
createuser --superuser root
psql> create database root owner root
```

After that, when logged in as root, you should be able to do what you want with the postgres user.

Comment: Are you saying to type that inside `psql`? It didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @hobbes3 No, from the regular shell, not in psql.

Comment: @hobbes3 Don't have a gentoo box handy, just an ubuntu, the paths may not be set up if you're having a problem.

Comment: Why it's `create database` for actually creating a user?

Answer (score 8):

You can try

```
update pg_authid set rolname ='root' where rolname = 'postgres';
```

But be aware, that munching the system catalogues by hand is always a little dangerous.

Comment: That seems to work. What's the difference between a role and a user? Was I logged in as `postgres` user or role when I did `psql -U postgres`?

Comment: @hobbes3: AFAIK "user" and "group" are the historic terms which were then collapsed into "role". So these terms are interchangeable to a great degree. So you were logged in with the role/user "postgres".

Comment: @hobbes3: In modern PostgreSQL, "users" are [roles with a login](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createuser.html), "groups" are without. Internally there are only roles.

Comment: @A.H. Thanks for the heads up on "munching system catalogues", I thought I'd save 5 minutes doing it this way. Instead I cost myself about an hour (I broke it). Just as a hint to anyone else: remove postgres & the dependencies with --purge (apt-get) if you need to reinstall.

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres RENAME TO root;
```

using a different superuser role?

Comment: "ERROR: session user cannot be renamed". Note, that OP was logged in as `postgres`.

Answer (score 6):

In order to rename current user `oldname` to `newname`, first log in as `oldname` and create a temporary superuser as such:

```sql
CREATE ROLE temp LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'mytemporarypassword';
```

Log out, then log in using the `temp` superuser and rename the `oldname` user. You will have to reset the password for that user at the same time, as PostgreSQL will tell you: "MD5 password cleared because of role rename".

```sql
ALTER ROLE oldname RENAME TO newname;
ALTER USER newname WITH PASSWORD 'My-Mega-5ecure-P4ssw0rd';
```

Now log in using the `newname` user and remove the temporary user that we created previously:

```sql
DROP ROLE temp;
```